# Can't get any Firebase features to work in Javascript Web app

Tags: javascript, firebase

Building a simple web app to access data in a Firestore db. My code seems to get stuck as soon as any Firebase function calls are made, but the Firebase console for my project shows reads to the database. I have experience with Firebase in Swift, but not much in Javascript and I'm pretty stumped here. Here's my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
    h1 {text-align: center;}
    h2 {text-align: center;}
    h3 {text-align: center;}
    form {text-align: center;}
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Endurance Database Access</title>
</head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script>
        const firebase = require('firebase/app');
        require("firebase/auth");
        require("firebase/firestore");
        var firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "-",
            authDomain: "-",
            databaseURL: "-",
            projectId: "-",
            storageBucket: "-",
            messagingSenderId: "-",
            appId: "-",
            measurementId: "-"
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        firebase.analytics();
    </script>

    <h1>Endurance Database Access</h1>
    <h2>Client Lookup</h2>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="cli" placeholder="Client name"><br>
    </form>
    <div id="button-div" style="text-align: center;">
        <button type="button" id="cli-btn">Search</button>
    </div>

    <script>
        const search_button = document.getElementById("cli-btn")
        search_button.addEventListener("click", function() {
            var client = document.getElementById("cli").value
            var clientRef = firebase.firestore().collection("clients");
            clientRef.where("Name", "==", client)
            .get()
            .then(function(querySnapshot) {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                    alert(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
                });
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                alert("Error getting documents: ", error);
            });
        });   
    </script>
  </body>
```

Any alert after the initializeApp() call won't show, and my search_button event listener isn't displaying any output either.
Here's my package.json as well:

```
{
  "name": "endurance-database",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Daniel Licht",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^7.14.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: `require` isn't a standard JS function and unless you're using [Require.js](https://requirejs.org/), isn't something you'd typically do in the browser. When you include the Firebase scripts via `<script>` tag, the objects should be available without `require`. Also, you don't appear to be using your browser's developer console to check for errors

Comment: I suggest you follow the _"From the CDN"_ examples here ~ https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#from-the-cdn

Comment: Hey Phil. That actually sounds like a pretty decent answer. Wanna post it, so Daniel can accept it? :)

Comment: @Phil thanks for the help!